# Can any finite lattice be realized as an intermediate subgroups lattice?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, open-problems, lattice-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup.
Let $\mathcal{L}(H \subset G )$ be  the lattice of all the intermediate subgroups between $H$ and $G$.

**Question:** Can any finite lattice be realized as an intermediate subgroups lattice?

*Remark*: It's true for all the finite distributive lattices (see theorem 2.1 [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~williamdemeo/latticetheory/Palfy-IntervalsInSubgroupLattices-GStA-1993.pdf)).

Comment: Take a look at http://authors.library.caltech.edu/13447/1/ASCjams08.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an open problem. See

- Wikipedia article: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_lattice_representation_problem
- [Palfy and Pudlak](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=593011)'s result (see open-source description in Palfy's article [Intervals in subgroup lattices of finite groups](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~williamdemeo/latticetheory/Palfy-IntervalsInSubgroupLattices-GStA-1993.pdf))
- This MO question from 2012: [Given a lattice L with n elements, are there finite groups H < G such that L $\cong$ the lattice of subgroups between H and G?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85724/given-a-lattice-l-with-n-elements-are-there-finite-groups-h-g-such-that-l-c)

Comment: Thank you! I observe that Palfy believes it's not true (see the sentence before theorem 1.7 p 484), so because his paper is more than 20 years old, perhaps we know a counter-example today.

Comment: The section 4 of Palfy's paper is dedicated to height 2 lattices. Is it still open in this case? Else, are they some progress since 20 years?

Comment: $M_{19}$ is not correct, the list of small values $n$ for which there is not a known representation for $M_{n}$ was, in Palfy's paper (p487): $n=16, 23, 35, 36, 37, 40...$.

Comment: I've unaccepted your answer because I've found recent advanced (2013) of the problem (see my answer). Are you agree with this decision?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Your answer is very interesting! As for whether to accept my answer or your own answer you might go by this: *Questions that turn out to be less-famous open problems, but still well-known to experts, are answered by giving a reference to somewhere that the openness of the problem is discussed.* -- Noah Snyder, http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/368/4600

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen For the second bullet point of your answer, I recommend using the link [http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=593011](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=593011). (The bullet point says "Palfy and Pudlak's result" but your link points a broad overview of the problem... albeit a very nice one.)

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo mahalo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

The more recent paper I've found about this problem is by Michael Aschbacher in 2013:
 [Overgroup lattices in finite groups of Lie type containing
a parabolic](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869313000847/1-s2.0-S0021869313000847-main.pdf?_tid=2f8219d8-b03e-11e4-8faa-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1423474366_aa3f3e97d7423ea941a91ef949e3125c)

His introduction is a short survey of the last advanced, he recall Palfy–Pudlak theorem and question, and focus on the following [John Shareshian](https://mathoverflow.net/users/36466/john-shareshian)'s conjecture. His paper is a first step for a proof of this conjecture:

Let $B_n$ be the subgroups lattice of the cyclic group $C_m$ with $m=p_1p_2 \dots p_n$ square free and $p_i$ prime number.
Let $\mathcal{L}$  be a finite lattice and $\mathcal{L}'$ the poset $\mathcal{L}-\{l,g  \}$ with $l$ and $g$ the least and greatest elements of $\mathcal{L}$.

**Shareshian's Conjecture**: If $\mathcal{L}'$ is a disconnected graph with connected components $(B'_{n_i})_{i=1, \dots , k}$ and  $n_i \ge 3$, then $\mathcal{L}$ is not an intermediate subgroups lattice.

The smallest lattice $\mathcal{L}$ coming from this conjecture is the following:

[image]

with $k=2$, $n_1=n_2=3$

Comment: This picture is not quite right.  The top and bottom elements from each Boolean algebra should be removed.  (That is, the two coatoms and the two atoms in the picture should not be there.)  To be clear, I do not know whether the pictured lattice is isomorphic with an interval in the subgroup lattice of a finite group.

Comment: One more small correction.  I believe that the conjecture you attribute to me is a special case of two more general conjectures, one due to Michael Aschbacher and the other due to me.

Comment: @JohnShareshian: Thank you, I will fix the picture. Michael Aschbacher attributes this conjecture to you in his paper above p72. Do you prefer I call it Aschbacher-Shareshian's conjecture?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I won't argue with Michael.